# how to restrict access to wp-login.php by IP address on nginx

Tags: nginx, security, wordpress

I have the following configuration for my wp site which is running on nginx 1.8.1

`location ^~ /wp-login.php {
        allow 10.0.0.0/24;
        deny all;
}`

```
location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
}
```

When I opening http://example.com/wp-login.php from my LAN, it downloads php file instead of passing it to fastcgi. After that I added all fastcgi lines inside of wp-login.php location and it began to work.

```
location ^~ /wp-login.php {
        allow 10.0.0.0/24;
        deny all;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

But is that the only way? Can I make a ordering of passing specific pattern on nginx?

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: Can I make a ordering of passing specific pattern on nginx?

Comment: [Sure](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Once nginx has selected a location block to serve a request, it generally stays within that location block. Only if there's some kind of internal redirect - i.e. you do a `rewrite` on the URI, `try_files` or `index` or `error_page` - then the request will be re-evaluated and a different location might end up serving the request.

Rather than trying to write your configuration to pass a request through multiple location blocks, you should instead consider using `include` and configuration snippets kept in other files so that configuration shared between multiple locations can be kept in a single file - it's simpler, is the same effort saving when it comes to duplicated configuration and it performs better than redirecting.